# How to let the functions in the helper script do not need take the parameters?

Tags: python

I have the script named "helper.py", and I have a script named "model.py".

Basically, the helper.py can save the parameters into a file, I simply this feature to be print out here. The "model.py" can produce 10 parameters.

Here is what I am dreaming:

```
# helper.py
def save():
    print(a1)
    print(a2)
    ......

# model.py

# (here get the parameters a1 a2....)
from helper import save 
save()                       # how neat it looks like!
```

This will went wrong because the parameters is not appeared in the helper.py. 
So what I am dreamed is I want this can print out all those parameters produced above. (Instead to write the function like this:)

```
# helper second edition.py
def save(a1, a2, a3, ...):   # this seems not efficient
    print(a1)
    print(a2)
    ......
```

Or this is just the case that does not suitable for calling helpers from other scripts? Because the functions must need the parameters in its script?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: Explicitely passing the parameters makes your code much clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: You can use `def save(*args): ...` to capture a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Hi I understand that, but I am afraid that will be mess if I need to save them into a file. I mean it would be easier not using the function just write the code for each one. Maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct and cleanest way to do it:

```
# helper.py
def save(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)


# model.py
from helper import save 

a1, a2, a3 = "foo", "bar", "baz"
save(a1, a2, a3)
```

But this is only if you want to call the function with varying amount of arguments. If you always pass the same amount of arguments, then it's best to just define the function to always take them all:

```
def save(a1, a2, a3):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! what if I want the function do different things to the parameters? For example: print (a1), f.write("this is the second one {}.".format(a2))...and so on

Comment: @rewove If you always have the same amount of arguments, then it's best to just define the function to always take them all `def save(a1, a2, a3):`.

Comment: @rewove that you could do like this: `print(args[0]); f.write("second arg".format(args[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword arguments, like so:

```
>>> def save(**kwargs):
...   print(kwargs['a1'])
...   print(kwargs['a2'])
... 
>>> save(**{'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'bar'})
foo
bar
```

See also [*args and **kwargs in python explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Thanks for your time! I am really a beginner to forget this feature. I found that is this possible to do different  things to them: For example: print (a1), f.write("this is the second one {}.".format(a2))...and so on

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to pass the arguments into the function. But as noted by a_guest and as you mentioned, there are two ways to do it:

1. Manually add in each of the parameters needed The advantage with this approach is that it's explicit about what is needed for this function to work. The downside is that you need to pass in all of the parameters, even if you only have 2 out of the 10
2. You can opt to use `*args` or `**kwargs`. `*args` will give you a function that can take in any number of positional parameters (e.g. calling `foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` or `foo(1,2,3)` ). The alternative would be to use `**kwargs` which provides an unlimited number of (distinct) keyword arguments (KeyWord, hence _kw_args). This would instead look like `foo(key1="val1", key2="val2")`.  Or, depending on your needs, you can use both. The code below demonstrates this

```py
def save(*args, **kwargs):
  if len(args) > 0:
    print("Got passed positional arguments: {}".format(args))
  if len(kwargs) > 0:
    for k, v in kwargs.items():  # iter_items if python 2
      print("Got passed keyword arguments: {}:{}".format(k, v) )
```

A couple of notes:
 1. `*args` will treat the input as a list
 2. `**kwargs` will treat the input as a dictionary

Comment: Thanks for explaining, your explanation is very complement and useful for me to understand! I will investigate more of it. Thanks!